# String array pass to another activity - android studio

Tags: java, android, arrays, nullpointerexception

I am trying to pass a string array to another activity with using intent; here are my intent codes:

```
private void activityGecis2() {
    Intent gecis2 = new Intent(this, dizilisActivity.class);
    gecis2.putExtra("isimler",oyuncular);
    startActivity(gecis2);
```

When I passed them I want to set them as textview text. but `gelenIsimler` returns null. So here are codes so what should I do?

```
public class dizilisActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView oyuncu1, oyuncu2,oyuncu3,oyuncu4,oyuncu5,oyuncu6,oyuncu7,oyuncu8,oyuncu9,oyuncu10;
    TextView[] oyuncular = {oyuncu1, oyuncu2,oyuncu3,oyuncu4,oyuncu5,oyuncu6,oyuncu7,oyuncu8,oyuncu9,oyuncu10};
     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dizilis);
        String[] gelenIsimler = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("isimler");


        oyuncu1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.oyuncu1);
        oyuncu2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.oyuncu2);
        oyuncu3= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.oyuncu3);
        oyuncu4= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.oyuncu4);
        oyuncu5= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.oyuncu5);
        oyuncu6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.oyuncu6);
        oyuncu7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.oyuncu7);
        oyuncu8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.oyuncu8);
        oyuncu9 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.oyuncu9);
        oyuncu10 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.oyuncu10);

for (int i = 0; i < oyuncular.length; i++ )
    oyuncular[i].setText(gelenIsimler[i]);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the series sent with the **Bundle**.

> Bundles are generally used for passing data between various Android
>   activities. It depends on you what type of values you want to pass,
>   but bundles can hold all types of values and pass them to the new
>   activity.

```
Bundle extras =  getIntent().getExtras();
String[] gelenIsimler = extras.getStringArrayExtra("isimler");
```

Solution - 2

```
Bundle b=new Bundle();
b.putStringArray("isimler", oyuncular);
Intent intent=new Intent(this, dizilisActivity.class);
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Other Activity**

```
 Intent intent=getIntent();
 Bundle b=intent.getExtras();
 String[] array=b.getStringArray("isimler");
```

Comment: getStringArrayExtra için cant resolve method hatası alıyorum
getStringArray yaptığımda da null dönebilir diyor

Comment: You have to get the data first with the Bundle.

Comment: I tried bundle but I am still getting null in for loop. There is something wrong with for loop?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like below

```
private void activityGecis2() {
    Intent gecis2 = new Intent(this, dizilisActivity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putStringArray("isimler", oyuncular);
    gecis2.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(gecis2);
}
```

In `dizilisActivity` get the array like below

```
String[] gelenIsimler = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray("isimler");
```

Comment: I write code but I am still getting null in for loop. There is something wrong with for loop?

Comment: For loop looks fine. Add a breakpoint at bundle.putStringArray("isimler", oyuncular); and confirm oyuncular is not null. Or one of the element in your array is null

Comment: I added but it says `oyuncular[i].setText(gelenIsimler[i]);` that is null

Comment: Share logcat details

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.easoft.aldimverdim.dizilisActivity.onCreate(dizilisActivity.java:32)`
line 32 is:
`oyuncular[i].setText(gelenIsimler[i]);`

Comment: One of your TextView is null

Comment: just second activity codes giving null bundle.getStringArray is giving null